# putting index on datetime!

Tags: sql-server

i have a table called livesessionhistory , i search it's record based on datetime . the size of the table is around 400,000 records . its taking too much time for the records to get fetched . so i added a index to the datetime. but unfortunatly the index did not helped.

also , all records are searched based on this datetime , so can i make it a clustered index ?

there are some columns which are some times added in search along with datetime , one of whcih is a are nullable long , will i be able to add that to a new non-clustered composite index ?

thanks
Jamal.

Comment: though the column type is datetime , when i am searching i can skip the time part of it .

Comment: Post the exact table structure, the index definitions (all of them) and the exact query you're running.

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index has the potential to help, although it also has the potential to hinder due to fragmentation, depends whether your data is added in sequence, and subsequent edits to the data.

Just adding an NC index on datetime would only help in very narrow searches, by the lack of clustered index already existing, the NC index just has the datetime and the row address, so is unlikely to cover the queries - as a result your query will often ignore the index and just scan. For a detailed explanation of how / why / when, Kimberley Tripp's Tipping Point article is a good read.

If you are on 2005+ Enterprise edition you could consider partitioning the table, 1 partition per month or week depending on your date range - given your queries always use that column is makes for an ideal partition key as well as providing you benefits when managing the data (archival, backup etc)